# JustGage - Can't refresh my php script using AJAX (and there is no working code available on stackoverflow)

Tags: ajax, raphael, graphael, justgage

SOLVED! Use my code!

I just can't use Ajax to refresh my result in JustGage. I've checked another post on Stackoverflow but this does not work. Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong with the last setInterval function.
Thanks!

Matt

```
    <!doctype html>

        <html>
          <head>
            <title>Customize style</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />

            <style>
              body {
                text-align: center;
              }


              p {
                display: block;
                width: 450px;
                margin: 2em auto;
                text-align: left;
              }
            </style>
            <script src="resources/js/raphael.2.1.0.min.js"></script>
            <script src="resources/js/justgage.1.0.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
            <script>
              var g1;

              window.onload = function(){
              var g1 = new JustGage({
                id: "g1", 
                value: getRandomInt(500, 600), 
                min: 0,
                max: 1500,
                title: "CO",
                label: "ppm",    
                gaugeWidthScale: 0.3          
              });

 var myvar='';
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url: 'g1CO.php',
    dataType:'text',
    success: function(data) {
        useReturnData(data);
    }
});

function useReturnData(data){
    myvar = data;
    console.log(myvar);
};



         setInterval(function() {
          //$.get('g1CO.php', function(data) { g1.refresh(myvar); });
        $.get("g1CO.php", function(data) {  g1.refresh(data)});   
        }, 2500);
      };
            </script>

            </head>
          <body>

        <table border="0">
        <tr>
        <td><div id="g1" style="width:300px; height:200px"></div></td>

        </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: can you provide www.jsfiddle.net please

Answer (score 0):

Use `g.refresh(newValue)`.

```
  var g1, g2;

  window.onload = function(){

    var g1 = new JustGage({
      id: "cpugauge", 
      value: 0, 
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: "CPU",
      label: "Load"
    });

    var g2 = new JustGage({
      id: "memgauge", 
      value: 0, 
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      title: "Memory",
      label: "Used"
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        $.get('ajax/cpu.php', function (newValue) { g1.refresh(newValue); });
        $.get('ajax/mem.php', function (newValue) { g2.refresh(newValue); });          
    }, 2500);
  };
```